# How to open and read a file with specific time stamp?

Tags: python

I am writing a script that will run daily, and open up a log file for that specific date. There is a collection of logs which are named like this: File-MMDDYYYYHHMMSS.log (example of Jan.1 2023 at 10:45 am would be File-01012023104500.log). The time is arbitrary and can happen at any time.

I tried the following:
import glob
textfile=glob.glob('File-*.log')
But not sure how to account for the date of today?

I am expecting that I have a way to open only the log file of the day the code is executed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `datetime.date` to get today's date and put it in the desired filename format:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date.today()
datetime.date(2023, 1, 4)
>>> datetime.date.today().strftime("File-%m%d%Y*.log")
'File-01042023*.log'
```